# Setting up Java Version to be used by PySpark in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, java, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

When trying to run PySpark in my Jupyter Notebook in VSCode I run into the following error message after the following lines of code:

```
import pyspark

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import findspark # part of my google work on the problem - didn't help...

spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('Practise').getOrCreate()
```

> ````
> calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.\n:
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class
> org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x34d2e626)
> cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base)
> because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module
> @0x34d2e626\n\tat
> org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:213)\n\tat
> org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)\n\tat
> org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)\n\tat
> org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)\n\tat
> org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)\n\tat
> org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)\n\tat
> org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)\n\tat
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)\n\tat
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)\n\tat
> org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)\n\tat
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)\n\tat
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)\n\tat
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)\n\tat
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)\n\tat
> py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)\n\tat
> py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)\n\tat
> py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)\n\tat
> py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\n", ```
> ````

The error message goes on but I think this is the relevant part. By doing some google work I found that this probably hints that the wrong version of Java is used (if not I might've to change the headline of this thread). On my Mac I got Java 18 and 8 installed. In my Terminal I can switch between versions like this:

```
JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.1.1.jdk/Contents/Home'
JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home'
```

However, in my notebook this does not seem to work:

```
!export JAVA_HOME='/Users/_______/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home'
!java -version
```

Output is still:

```
java version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2-6, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Is there a solution other than completely removing the newer Java-Version from my Mac (or is the problem actually a completely different one)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the correct version of Java installed, but it's not the default version for your operating system, you can update your system `PATH` environment variable dynamically, or set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable within Python before creating your Spark context.

Your two options would look like this:

## Set JAVA_HOME

```py
import os

JAVA_HOME = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home"
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = JAVA_HOME

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('Practise').getOrCreate()
```

## Add Java bin to PATH

```py
import os

JAVA_HOME = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home"
os.environ["PATH"] = f"{JAVA_HOME}/bin:{os.environ['PATH']}"  # Note /bin is added to JAVA_HOME path.

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('Practise').getOrCreate()
```